# Use a subdirectory as root with htaccess in Apache 1.3

Tags: apache, .htaccess, jekyll, subdirectory

I'm trying to deploy a site generated with Jekyll and would like to keep the site in its own subfolder on my server to keep everything more organized.

Essentially, I'd like to use the contents of `/jekyll` as the root unless a file similarly named exists in the actual web root. So something like `/jekyll/sample-page/` would show as http://www.example.com/sample-page/, while something like `/other-folder/` would display as http://www.example.com/other-folder.

My test server runs Apache 2.2 and the following `.htaccess` (adapted from http://gist.github.com/97822) works flawlessly:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Map http://www.example.com to /jekyll.
RewriteRule ^$ /jekyll/ [L]

# Map http://www.example.com/x to /jekyll/x unless there is a x in the web root.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/jekyll/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /jekyll/$1

# Add trailing slash to directories without them so DirectoryIndex works.
# This does not expose the internal URL.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/

# Disable auto-adding slashes to directories without them, since this happens
# after mod_rewrite and exposes the rewritten internal URL, e.g. turning
# http://www.example.com/about into http://www.example.com/jekyll/about.
DirectorySlash off
```

However, my production server runs Apache 1.3, which doesn't allow `DirectorySlash`. If I disable it, the server gives a 500 error because of internal redirect overload.

If I comment out the last section of ReWriteConds and rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/
```

…everything mostly works: http://www.example.com/sample-page/ displays the correct content. However, if I omit the trailing slash, the URL in the address bar exposes the real internal URL structure: http://www.example.com/jekyll/sample-page/

What is the best way to account for directory slashes in Apache 1.3, where useful tools like `DirectorySlash` don't exist? How can I use the `/jekyll/` directory as the site root without revealing the actual URL structure?

**Edit:**

After a ton of research into Apache 1.3, I've found that this problem is essentially a combination of two different issues listed at the [Apache 1.3 URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/rewriteguide.html).

I have a (partially) moved DocumentRoot, which in theory would be taken care of with something like this:

```
RewriteRule   ^/$  /e/www/  [R]
```

I also have the infamous "Trailing Slash Problem," which is solved by setting the `RewriteBase` (as was suggested in one of the responses below):

```
RewriteBase    /~quux/
RewriteRule    ^foo$  foo/  [R]
```

The problem is combining the two. Moving the document root doesn't (can't?) use `RewriteBase`—fixing trailing slashes requires(?) it… Hmm…

Comment: this is awesome. If I have multiple domains pointing to a server, is there a way I can apply the above rules in a conditional manner? thus, if request from domainA.com then expose /domainA/ subfolder as if it was root.. and if request from domainB.com, then expose subdir /domainB/ as if it were the root?

Comment: @bkwdesign use nginx, it's much simpler for this kind of redirection.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Finally got it, after a week of trying. RewriteRules really are voodoo…

```
RewriteEngine On

# Map http://www.example.com to /jekyll.
RewriteRule ^$ /jekyll/ [L]

# Map http://www.example.com/x to /jekyll/x unless there is a x in the web root.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/jekyll/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /jekyll/$1

# Add trailing slash to directories within jekyll
# This does not expose the internal URL.
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^jekyll/(.*[^/])$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301]
```

No need for `DirectorySlash`. It magically all works.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Took me hours to find this solution, but it's perfect and works everywhere so far! Thank you very much.

Comment: One more thing: But how can I make this forcing https? I put the following code in front, but I'm not sure if this is a good solution:
`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]`

Answer (score 14):

You can simply use:

```
RewriteBase   /jekyll
```

And everything starts from that point.

Comment: This answer is better!!

Comment: This one doesn't work for me at my hosting, the answer above does.

Comment: Does this one works if you have another service in the home url like a shortener ?? the first answer does, so just wondering

Answer (score 5):

The only simple solution worked for me is [here](https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_change_my_document_root_folder_using_an_htaccess_file/)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1 [L]
```

Put this code into your .htaccess file.

> domain-name.com – Type your own domain name

> folder – Type the name of the subfolder which has the test/development website