# htaccess: remove subdirectory form URL while serving up original content

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, expressionengine

I have a URL structure like this

```
http://domain.com/page/thing1
http://domain.com/page/thing2
http://domain.com/page/thing3
```

**I want to:**

- remove /page/ from the URL
- serve up content from /page/thing1

I am using ExpressionEngine, so here's what I do to remove index.php from the URL

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        # Removes index.php
        RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You don't necessarily have to do this via ModRewrite, depending on how you're accessing this data in EE. Are these URLs created via the Pages module? Or is `page` a template group and `thing1` a template? Or are `thing1`, `thing2` etc, all entry URL titles?

Comment: Here are two posts which may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402140/use-a-subdirectory-as-root-with-htaccess-in-apache-1-3 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990392/htaccess-rewrite-to-redirect-root-url-to-subdirectory

Comment: @DerekHogue right now I have it set up where page is a template group and thing1 and thing 2 are entries.

Comment: In that case, [see rjb's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8890130/174299) - the Pages module is the way to go here. Accessing individual entries by their URL title via the first segment is not a good route to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What are the gains to be had from these new URLs?**

Simply removing the `/page` URL segment (i.e. template group) from your URIs creates a lot of additional overhead and complexity, as illustrated in the following [ExpressionEngine URL Schematic](http://www.jamessmith.co.uk/articles/expressionengine_url_schematic):

[image: ExpressionEngine URL Schematic]

The native ExpressionEngine [Pages Module](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/pages/index.html) or the third-party [Structure Module](http://buildwithstructure.com/) is the simplest method and won't require adding any RewriteRules rules to your `.htaccess` file.

However, this will require you to *create a page* URL for each entry, which may be less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

If you change all your urls to be http://domain.com/thing1 and http://domain.com/thing2 etc, couldn't you just add the *page/* back in when you rewrite to the index.php file?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/page/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This would assume *all requests* would be routed thru the `/pages` template group, which would break many URIs — including many core ExpressionEngine URLs. At a minimum, you'd have to combine the `RewriteRule` with a `RewriteCond`.

Answer (score 0):

Append these lines below your existing Rewrite rule in `IfModule` block:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!page/)(.*)$ /page/$1 [L,NC]
```